# how java interface can methods of object class

Tags: java, interface

I have question on interfaces.  If I write the below piece of code in Eclipse, why is it not giving an error while writing the code and how does it get all methods of the string class?

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      TestI ti = null;
      ti.toString();
   }
}

interface TestI
{}
```

Comment: `toString()` is comming from `Object` if that is the question

Comment: Any implementation of `TestI` would have to be a concrete class. Any concrete class must `extends Object`.

Comment: Have you compiled this code? `string` should be `String`. Have you run it? `null.toString()` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I think you over simplified this example too much from your original code, as this does give an error as @EricJablow pointed out. (A runtime one anyway). If you change `null` to `new TestI(){};` then you'll this will run. An as others have said, it is an object so it has `toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

All classes by default extend `Object` class implicitly.  And `Object` class has `toString()` method.

But it will be `java.lang.NullPointerException` in runtime.

Comment: An object has `toString()`. But `null` does not which is what he set `ti` to.

Comment: @Cruncher but eclipse doesn't know that "while writing the code"

Comment: @clcto right, this is a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

ti is an Object and Object has list functions -

Ref: [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Comment: `ti` is a reference. A `null` reference at that, and absolutely does not point to an object.

Comment: correct... hence it doesn't give a compile time error. but will sure give a runtime.

Answer (score 0):

What error do you expect it to be giving?

Interfaces are reference types, so when you define your interface TestI, you can use that as a data type. (TestI ti = null)

Interfaces implicitly declares a public abstract member method corresponding to each public instance method declared in the Object class, unless a method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by that interface. -- This means you can call any method the Object class has unless its declared in your interface. It is not "inheriting" from the Object class.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2